# VC++ COLORREF with alpha value

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, colors, mfc

As long as I understand the defined `COLORREF` in VC++ is a DWORD which looks like this `0x00bbggrr` where `bb, gg` and `rr` are bytes that are used for red, green and blue. Microsoft's documentation states that

> The high-order byte must be zero.

However in .NET it is used for storing alpha value of the color. 
My question is:

Is it dangerous to store my alpha value in the high byte of COLORREF

Comment: APIs that expect `COLORREF` exactly might ignore most significant bits or fail since the value does not pass strict validation "...must be zero". At other times the value might be actually [`OLE_COLOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with special meaning of highest bits. You can use the spare bits when it's internal use only but once you release the values to the APIs be ready for surprises.

Answer (score 5):

> However in .NET it is used for storing alpha value of the color

It doesn't.  COLORREF is a typedef for GDI, the legacy api for graphics and goes back to Windows version 3.0.  Strictly a 24bpp api and doesn't know beans about alpha, there was no hardware for it back then.  Color palettes were the vogue, they have no use for alpha.  Pretty unpleasant programming btw, I've lost quite a few hairs over RealizePalette().

.NET uses GDI+.  First exposed as a C++ api in the gdiplus.h SDK header and released ~8 years after Win3.  Catching up with evolving hardware, it supports 32bpp and an alpha channel.  It uses a very different definition for color values, the [Color type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Which is incompatible with COLORREF in more than just the added alpha channel, it also stores the colors in the exact opposite way.  Format is 0xaarrggbb.  Might have been intentional, makes it easy to see when the code accidentally uses a COLORREF incorrectly :)

Not sure where you saw COLORREF being used, the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) has no match.  I'm curious, update your question with a link.

Comment: Excuse me., my mistake! Yes there is a class for Color. However i am working on a system which has much of a history and one of the main objects uses color with COLORREF. And that is the way it is serialized. The problem is when it comes to change the serialization that will make all the previous version of this object hard to maintain. So the easiest way in terms of support is to use already serialized COLORREF and store the alpha in it so the previous version will be able to open the objects made with the newer one.

Comment: It is up to you to make that work.  Should not be a problem since a disk or network doesn't care what a color looks like, you still have 32 bits at your disposal.  Just convert with the Color.FromArgb() and ToArgb() functions and cast the int.  Whether you need to reverse the bytes is something you'll have to find out, test with old serialized data.  Crystal ball says you don't have to.